# Firefox CSS rotation differs from Chrome rotation

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I want to make a 3D rectangle (parallelepiped) which the users can move with the arrows. It works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox some transitions (a lot actually) are different from Chrome. Look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7273yur9/2/) fiddle (this is my whole code) and compare it in both browsers to understand better.

Because the first fiddle contains a lot of code, I'll simplify it and pick one random strange transition. Look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/L36v50kh/) fiddle, and press the "Left" button or the left arrow one time. It works fine, but when you press it again, the rectangle rotates 3 times instead of 1 time.

Is this a Firefox bug or what am I doing wrong?

The code below is what you'll find in the simplified fiddle.

```js
var position = 'show-front';

$('#left').bind('click', function() {
    if (position == 'show-front') {
        $('#box').removeClass().addClass('show-right');
        position = 'show-right';
    } else if (position == 'show-right') {
        $('#box').removeClass().addClass('show-back-3');
        position = 'show-back-3';
    } else if (position == 'show-back-3') {
        $('#box').removeClass().addClass('show-left');
        position = 'show-left';
    } else if (position == 'show-left') {
        $('#box').removeClass().addClass('show-front');
        position = 'show-front';
    }
});
    
$(window).bind('keyup', function(event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 37: // left
            $('#left').click();
            break;
    }
});
```

```css
.container {
width: 150px;
height: 100px;
position: relative;
margin: 25px auto 25px auto;
perspective: 600px;
}

#box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 1s;
}

#box figure {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;
    line-height: 98px;
    font-size: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}

figure {
    margin: 0;
}

#box .front,
#box .back {
    width: 148px;
    height: 98px;
}

#box .right,
#box .left {
    width: 48px;
    height: 98px;
    left: 50px;
}

#box .top,
#box .bottom {
    width: 148px;
    height: 48px;
    top: 25px;
    line-height: 48px;
}

#box .front {
    background: hsla(000, 100%, 50%, 0.7);
}

#box .back {
    background: hsla(160, 100%, 50%, 0.7);
}

#box .right {
    background: hsla(120, 100%, 50%, 0.7);
}

#box .left {
    background: hsla(180, 100%, 50%, 0.7);
}

#box .top {
    background: hsla(240, 100%, 50%, 0.7);
}

#box .bottom {
    background: hsla(300, 100%, 50%, 0.7);
}

#box .front {
    transform: translateZ(25px);
}

#box .back {
    transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(25px);
}

#box .right {
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(75px);
}

#box .left {
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(75px);
}

#box .top {
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(50px);
}

#box .bottom {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
}

#box.show-front {
    transform: translateZ(-50px);
}

#box.show-right {
    transform: translateZ(-150px) rotateY(-90deg);
}

#box.show-back-3 {
    transform: translateZ(-50px) rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(-180deg);
}

#box.show-left {
    transform: translateZ(-150px) rotateY(90deg);
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
    <div id="box" class="show-front">
        <figure class="front">1</figure>
        <figure class="back">2</figure>
        <figure class="right">3</figure>
        <figure class="left">4</figure>
        <figure class="top">5</figure>
        <figure class="bottom">6</figure>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It looks like you aren't using `-moz-transform` and `-webkit-transform` for firefox and chrome respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the assumption that Firefox is just buggy in this regard (see analysis below), [here is a workaround](https://jsfiddle.net/955k5fhh/7/) that works on Firefox. It wraps the `#box` element in another `div`, and only transitions the wrapper. And the wrapper is only ever rotated 90 degrees from the starting point in one direction at a time, so Firefox can't mess it up.

Once the transition finishes, the rotation is reset back to the starting position and simultaneously the inner box is rotated to the new position, both without transition, so the change is not visible.

The second important change is using the current computed transformation of `#box` and adding the rotation to that, so that we don't have to keep track of the rotations as we go.

Note that the order of rotations matters. To achieve what you're trying to do (rotating in "world space" rather than "object space"), you need to apply the rotations in reverse order. E.g. to rotate "right", use `.css("transform", "rotateY(90deg) " + currentComputedTransform)`. This will resolve the issue you mentioned in comments where it appears to rotate around the wrong axis. See below for more information.

Note also that I don't allow a rotation to start if there's already one in progress, because that won't work. You could queue up keystrokes in an array if you want to be able to that, but you might also want to reduce the transition duration proportional to queue length in that case so it doesn't take forever.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/955k5fhh/7/

Relevant javascript:

```
$("#box").wrap("<div id='outer'></div>");
var pending=null;

function rotate(axis,angle,dir) {
    if (pending) return;
    $("#outer").removeClass().addClass(dir);
    var current=$("#box").css("transform");
    if (current=='none') current='';
    pending="rotate"+axis+"("+angle+"deg) "
      + current;
}

$("#outer").bind('transitionend', function() {
    $(this).removeClass();
    $("#box").css('transform',pending);
    pending=null;
});

$('#up').bind('click', function() {
    rotate('X',90,"up");
});

$('#down').bind('click', function() {
    rotate('X',-90,"down");
});

$('#right').bind('click', function() {
    rotate('Y',90,"right");
});

$('#left').bind('click', function() {
    rotate('Y',-90,"left");
});
```

---

### Previous analysis

I've been playing with JS-based solutions and I came across this useful post https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/67317 - it points out that to rotate objects in "world space" instead of "object space", you just need to reverse the order of the rotations.

Based on that, I simplified your fiddle to the following:

```
var rot = "";
var tr = "translateZ(-50px)";

$('#up').bind('click', function() {
    rot=" rotateX(90deg)"+rot;
    $("#box").css("transform",tr+rot);
});

$('#down').bind('click', function() {
    rot=" rotateX(-90deg)"+rot;
    $("#box").css("transform",tr+rot);
});

$('#right').bind('click', function() {
    rot=" rotateY(90deg)"+rot;
    $("#box").css("transform",tr+rot);
});

$('#left').bind('click', function() {
    rot=" rotateY(-90deg)"+rot;
    $("#box").css("transform",tr+rot);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/955k5fhh/ (note that it's not a complete solution, because eventually the `rot` string will get too long)

And on Chrome, that behaves as expected. And once again, Firefox gets it wrong, even if you're just chaining e.g. a sequence of `rotateX(90deg)` transformations.

So I went one step further and rolled up adjacent rotations in the same axis...

```
var rots = [];
var tr = "translateZ(-50px)";

function transform() {
    var tf = "translateZ(-50px)";
    rots.forEach(function(rot) {
        tf += " rotate" + rot[0] + "(" + rot[1] + "deg)";
    });
    console.log(tf);
    $("#box").css("transform", tf);
}

function addRot(axis,angle) {
    if (rots.length==0 || rots[0][0]!=axis) {
        rots.unshift([axis,angle]);
    } else {
        rots[0][1]+=angle;
    }
    transform();
}

$('#up').bind('click', function() {
    addRot('X',90);
});

$('#down').bind('click', function() {
    addRot('X',-90);
});

$('#right').bind('click', function() {
    addRot('Y',90);
});

$('#left').bind('click', function() {
    addRot('Y',-90);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/955k5fhh/2/

Which, again, works well in Chrome, and works a bit better in Firefox, but still once you switch axes, you can wind up spinning the wrong way. And similarly if you click a button before a transition completes, it can spin the wrong way.

So I would conclude that unfortunately yes, Firefox is just buggy in this, but at least there are workarounds.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution is perfect. Cross-browser compatibility, easy to understand, less code than I initially had, exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing everything right, and the differences in rotation in Chrome vs Firefox is caused by the ways the two browsers process CSS3. When looking at the rotation from `show-back-4` to `show-top-4`, your CSS file specifies the rotation to be `270deg`. In Firefox, it does just that. In Chrome, it looks like it optimizes and doesn't do the full rotation, saving on processing power or something. So yeah, I think that it's just a difference in the browsers, not a bug in either one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using keyframes to get more control for the animation, something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/L36v50kh/2/

I'm defining both starting and ending point for all transitions in the fiddle like this:

```
@keyframes front-to-right {
    from {transform: translateZ(-50px) rotateY(0deg); }
    to {transform:  translateZ(-150px) rotateY(-90deg);}
}
```

That looks the same in both browsers but it's jumpy when clicking the button before the animation finishes.

You might also consider animating with JavaScript to get exact control and avoid defining every transition, something like this:

```js
var applyRotation = function() {
    $('#box').css('transform', 'rotateY(' + rotateY + 'deg)');
    handleMultipleRotations();
};

var unwindTimeout;
var rotateY = 0;
var handleMultipleRotations = function() {
  $('#box').css('transition-duration', '');
  if (typeof unwindTimeout === 'number') {
    clearTimeout(unwindTimeout);
    unwindTimeout = undefined;
  }
  if (Math.abs(rotateY) >= 360) {
    unwindTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
      rotateY -= Math.floor(rotateY / 360) * 360;
      $('#box').css({
        'transition-duration': '0s',
        'transform': 'rotateY(' + rotateY + 'deg)'
      });

    }, 1000);
  }
};

$('document').ready(function() {
  $('#left').on('click', function() {
    rotateY -= 90;
    applyRotation();
  });
  $('#right').on('click', function() {
    rotateY += 90;
    applyRotation();
  });
});
```

```css
/* minified to draw focus to js */ .container{width:150px;height:100px;position:relative;margin:25px auto;perspective:600px}#box{width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;transform-style:preserve-3d;transition:transform 1s}#box figure{display:block;position:absolute;border:1px solid #000;line-height:98px;font-size:45px;text-align:center;font-weight:700;color:#fff}figure{margin:0}#box .back,#box .front{width:148px;height:98px}#box .left,#box .right{width:48px;height:98px;left:50px}#box .bottom,#box .top{width:148px;height:48px;top:25px;line-height:48px}#box .front{background:hsla(000,100%,50%,.7)}#box .back{background:hsla(160,100%,50%,.7)}#box .right{background:hsla(120,100%,50%,.7)}#box .left{background:hsla(180,100%,50%,.7)}#box .top{background:hsla(240,100%,50%,.7)}#box .bottom{background:hsla(300,100%,50%,.7)}#box .front{transform:translateZ(25px)}#box .back{transform:rotateX(180deg) translateZ(25px)}#box .right{transform:rotateY(90deg) translateZ(75px)}#box .left{transform:rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(75px)}#box .top{transform:rotateX(90deg) translateZ(50px)}#box .bottom{transform:rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50px)}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">
  <div id="box" class="show-front"><figure class="front">1</figure><figure class="back">2</figure><figure class="right">3</figure><figure class="left">4</figure><figure class="top">5</figure><figure class="bottom">6</figure></div>
</section>
<section id="options"><p><button id="left">Left</button><button id="right">Right</button></p></section>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, the keyframes css solution seems good, although I'll have to write a lot of code. I've also tried something with javascript, but I got the same results as with css, some transitions look weird.

Comment: Personally I prefer my other solution, how could it be improved to better fit your situation?

Comment: The biggest problem I've had when I tried with javascript was that I couldn't figure out a way to properly rotate the rectangle using the Z axis. I don't know if the rotations are relative to the current rectangle position or the start position, because from what I've done, sometimes they seemed to the start positions, sometimes to the current position.

Comment: The rotations are relative to 0 degrees. They are applied one at a time to the object so the order of the rotations matters. You might be getting confused with local vs global rotation (guessing from you naming the button "left" instead of "Y-").

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kfqzm9xx/ is what I've done with javascript, the problem, as I said, is that I can't figure out a rule for when I need to rotate Z axis, plus some rotations are correct, some go right when I press left or vice versa (see arrow up --> arrow up --> arrow left ==> it goes right).

Comment: The object is rotated along it's local X and Y axises not "left" or "up". [This illustrates the difference. (pressing right always rotates it to the direction of the R arrow)](https://jsfiddle.net/kfqzm9xx/2/) Google "rotation matrix" to get lots of reading. Or you could use the keyframe solution (or implement a similar solution in JS, i.e. predefine a rotation for each face) if you only need multiples of 90 degrees. If you decide to go for the css solution, you should probably use sass to trim down some of the code.

Comment: Tried now with css keyframes but unfortunately ran into the same problem, firefox seems "bugged". Although keyframe "top-2-back-4" tells him to go from "rotateX(270deg) rotateY(-90deg)" to "rotateX(270deg) rotateY(-90deg) rotateX(-90deg)", instead rotating X -90 deg it rotates it 270 deg. Example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1agp0nnw/