# CSS effect not working on Firefox

Tags: css

My CSS effect is missing. It is working perfectly in Chrome, but it won't work in Mozilla Firefox.

I tried `-webkit` and `-moz` prefixes. Without `-webkit` it's working in Chrome, but with `-moz` it is not working properly in Firefox.

```css
#perspective {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  perspective: 2500px;
}

#grid {
  padding-right: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 1000px;
  column-count: 4;
  column-gap: 0;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  transform-origin: top right;
  padding-left: 15px;
  transform: rotateX(50deg) rotateZ(-40deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  z-index: 1;
}

#grid a {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);

  /*transform-style: preserve-3d;*/
}

#grid .brick {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 0 0 #999;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

#grid .brick:hover {
  transform: rotateX(-20deg);
  z-index: 5;
  box-shadow: -5px 2px 0 0 #999;
}
```

```html
<div id="perspective">
    <div id="grid">
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The flips up effect does not work in Firefox.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The tiles in chrome flips up, although it would of been much better to put that in the question

Comment: Even with an autoprefixer, the result is not the same. A little googling took me to the same problem. I guess both renders it differently.

Comment: done that too but same result on mozila

Comment: This could be of some help https://stackoverflow.com/a/30287059

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem using "columns" in firefox with 3d transformations.

Remove:

```
column-count: 4;
column-gap: 0;
```

And for block wrapper (in your case #grid a) use

```
display: inline-block;
width:25%;
transform-style: preserve-3d;



#grid a {
  display: inline-block;
  width:25%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

```css
#perspective {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  perspective: 2500px;
}

#grid {
  padding-right: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 1000px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  transform-origin: top right;
  padding-left: 15px;
  transform: rotateX(50deg) rotateZ(-40deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  z-index: 1;
}

#grid a {
  display: inline-block;
  width:25%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#grid .brick {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 0 0 #999;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

#grid .brick:hover {
  transform: rotateX(-20deg);
  z-index: 5;
  box-shadow: -5px 2px 0 0 #999;
}
```

```html
<div id="perspective">
    <div id="grid">
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
      <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```